# See when I logged time on Jira?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to see when I logged time in Jira? I need to log 8 hours a day. Ive updated a number of tasks and I can see time spent but not when this time was spent.

Comment: Under profile you can see Tempo. Here you can see everything logged.

Comment: Where is this option? Im not sure we are using it.

Comment: I can see it in my overview on the right top under profile.

Comment: Options -> log work -> say 8h and you can select timings from calendar

Comment: I cant see "Options"